# Twitter Bootstrap Scrollspy Actviate Trigger

Tags: jquery

I've seen questions asked a million times but I can not seem to find a solution to my problem.

I'm currently trying to execute a function when a section is 'activated'. I'm hoping I'm phrasing this correctly. Scrollspy works with no issues but I am unable to trigger anything using this:

```
$('.ul.nav li').on('activate', function()
  {
   //do something
});
```

In testing whether or not I can get a response I'm trying to trigger a alert and I get zilch. What element is 'activate' binding to? The menu element? The section ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got 2 issues here:

1. You event is incorrect, you need `focus` I guess
2. Try event delegation on `on`

Your code should look like this:

```
$(document).on("focus", ".ul.nav li", function(event){
   //do something
});
```

Comment: Ahhhh, thank you so much! I replaced 'focus' with 'activate' and it works perfectly. Thanks!